# What is the correct way to convert "9:00 pm" to "21:00:00" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, time

First, I don't know what names I should be referring to each of these formats by, so forgive me for using a real example.

In PHP, I can easily convert string time to a timestamp, and then use that timestamp to create a time with any format of my choosing like this: `$timestamp = strtotime('9:00 am');
$militaryTime = date('H:i:s',$timestamp);
echo $militaryTime;`

But how do I do this in javascript? I simply don't understand which method in the JS `Date()` object i'd use to enter my initial time, then what method in the to use to convert the time, and so on

so, what is the correct way in javascript to transform "9:00 pm" to "21:00:00"?

Comment: You want to parse a string value like "9:00 p.m." and get a date value?

Comment: @EdgarT I'm assuming i *should* have to do that. is that not true in javascript?

Comment: If you're working with Date objects to start, the process is much simpler. If you are working with strings to start, it involves parsing, which isn't exactly complex, but does complicate the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/VxL4X/1/

```
var timeString = "7:33 PM";

var dateint = Date.parse("January 1, 2000 " + timeString);
var dateObj = new Date(dateint);
var milTime = dateObj.toLocaleTimeString();
var milTime2 = dateObj.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];

console.log(milTime);
console.log(milTime2);
```

I would probably suggest against using `toLocaleTimeString` if you expect this application to be international.

Another option is to manually construct the time string: http://jsfiddle.net/VxL4X/2/

```
var manualTime = 
    dateObj.getHours().pad(2) + ':' +
    dateObj.getMinutes().pad(2) + ':' +
    dateObj.getSeconds().pad(2);
```

(note the extension of the Number object with the `pad` function)

Comment: strangely the output sortof changes when you're using different browsers

Comment: @Kristian I'm not surprised. Are some browsers giving an inaccurate time, or is it just the format that is changing?

Comment: some end up with "xx:xx:xx" and some have "xx:xx:xx PM" (where x is a number)

Comment: Using `toTimeString` or `toLocaleTimeString`? This part: `.split(" ")[0]` was tacked onto `toTimeString` to remove the timezone information, so you could do the same thing for `toLocaleTimeString`, however, manually constructing the string is probably going to be the most consistent, though I haven't tested it across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to get the parts of the string:

```
var in = "9:00 pm";
var m = in.match(/(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}) ([ap])m/i);
m[1] = parseInt(m[1],10);
if( m[1] == 12) m[1] -= 12;
if( m[3].toLowerCase() == "p") m[1] += 12;
m[1] = m[1]%24;
var out = m[1]+":"+m[2];
```